# What morphological traits can be used to diagnose members of the Eucalypteae?

Tags: botany, terminology, taxonomy

I read the Wikipedia article on Eucalypteae and it doesn't actually say what these plants have in common.

(I am now reading through https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.3732/ajb.1200025 and I think I've found the answer to this question.)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In particular, what all taxonomic groupings have in common is an ancestor — however, this definitely falls under the category of "trivial to biology professionals" and so is a "homework" question. If that isn't the question you are trying to ask, please [edit] to clarify what you do want to know and to demonstrate your prior research effort.

Comment: Wouldn't that be all clades? With taxonomic groupings also being on the basis of traits?

Comment: Well, I'd say it is more a matter of inference  — what we care about is the evolutionary history. If we were to find that one group of eucalypts had a different ancestor, then those plants would be moved into a new group. The traits (now primarily based on DNA sequences) are the evidence used to determine relatedness — my understanding is morphological traits are now primarily field marks for diagnosing to what group an organism belongs. ——— At any rate, it seems your question is more about common traits, so I think it would be helpful to edit your question's title and body to emphasize that.

Comment: I've edited your title to something that seems clearer to me — please make additional changes if I'm still not understanding you correctly, or if you prefer a different wording.

Comment: If you're reading now the article that you link to in your question and you think it answers your question, then perhaps you might consider accepting my answer which linked to and quoted the same article (before you edited it into your link).

Comment: Couldn't find the place to click it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at the APG website ? http://www.mobot.org/mobot/research/APweb/orders/myrtalesweb2.htm#Eucalypteae it may give some interesting information ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a slightly tough question that can't be answered with a simple "they share X characteristic in common". It's more that some of them share a characteristic, and some of those share a characteristic with another load of species within the same sub-clade, and some of the characteristics they have are shared with some more... etc.
The [American Journal of Botany](https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.3732/ajb.1200025) puts it:

*(Synapomorphy: a shared trait believed to have been present in a common ancestor.)*

> Currently, no unambiguous morphological [synapomorphies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apomorphy_and_synapomorphy) have been confidently  identified as defining the Eucalypteae in comparison to other
> Myrtaceae (however, see Wilson et al., 2001 , for some possibilities).
> Within the Eucalypteae, however, subclades are defined by
> synapomorphies. For instance, Angophora Cav., Corymbia , and
> Eucalyptus share several possible synapomorphies, such as presence of
> oil glands that protrude above the surface of the epidermis (“emergent
> oil glands” of Ladiges, 1984 ).

> These are modified into distinctive
> bristle glands in Angophora and Corymbia ( Johnson, 1972 ; Ladiges,
> 1984 ), which are a unique synapomorphy for the Angophora - Corymbia
> clade ( Ladiges et al., 1995 ; Wilson et al., 2001 ). Angophora ,
> Corymbia , and Eucalyptus are also characterized by having compound
> petals and, in Eucalyptus, a portion of the compound petal is usually
> modified into a staminophore, or stamen-bearing tissue ( Drinnan and
> Ladiges, 1988 , 1989a , b ,  1991a ).

> Other characters are apomorphic
> but are likely homoplasious, having arisen more than once within
> Eucalypteae. For example, some Corymbia and Eucalyptus species are
> characterized by the presence of calycine and/or corolline opercula,
> or cap-like perianth whorls that are deciduous from the flower at or
> prior to anthesis (e.g., Johnson, 1972 ; Hill and Johnson, 1995 ;
> Boland et al., 2006 ). Opercula likely have separate origins in these
> genera ( Ladiges et al., 1995 ; Parra-O. et al., 2009 ). A caducous
> calyx that usually leaves a scar on the flower bud (see Johnson, 1972
> ; Boland et al., 2006 ) is also an apomorphic but homoplastic
> character within Eucalypteae, being a synapomorphy for a clade within
> Corymbia ( Ladiges et al., 1995 ;  Parra-O. et al., 2009 ) and having
> arisen at least once on the stem of Eucalyptus subgenus Symphyomyrtus
> ( Fig. 1B ).